# Using Impersonation in Blazor Server APP on IIS to authenticate against SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-authentication, blazor-server-side, impersonation

I have an intranet application I host on IIS using Windows Authentication. Now I need to authenticate the user against the SQL Server (run on the same server). This is the code I use. GetDbUser fires a simple `queryString = "SELECT suser_sname()";` to the SQL Server. I get an error:

> Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON.

So it seems impersonation is not working correctly. If I comment out the RunImpersonated code and run locally it works fine.

```
private async Task DbConnectionTest()
{
    var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
    user = authState.User;    

    _dataBaseUser = "";

    var Currentuser = (WindowsIdentity)user.Identity;

    WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(Currentuser.AccessToken, () =>
    {
        string dbUser = GetDbUser();
        _dataBaseUser = $"Database User-> {dbUser}";
    });
}
```

This is the code for the database

```
private string GetDbUser()
{
    string queryString = "SELECT suser_sname()";

    DataTable _table = new DataTable();

    string myConnectionString = "Server = MyMSSQLServer; Database = testDB; Trusted_Connection = True;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                _table.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
    return _table.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the configuration instructions for [IIS/IIS Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?#iisiis-express)? It sounds like you didn't disable Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: I Disabled Anonymous Authentication winauth works fine but not the impersonation part.

Comment: If you don't comment out the RunImpersonated code and run locally, can it work well? Asp.net core doesnot implement impersonation, if the app should perform an action on behalf of a user, RunImpersonated can do it. When you comment out the RunImpersonated code, it runs with the app's identity, not current user.

Comment: Sure. I was just pointing out that my IIS settings are correct thus far for windows authentication. But my impersonation code apparently isn't.

Comment: Does your IIS and database in the same domain and application pool have identity to login? Another thing is you can change the provider of windows,Negotiate, NTML, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Use AuthenticationStateProvider to obtain the Access Token

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

var token = ((WindowsIdentity)AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User.Identity).AccessToken;
```

rather than

```
var Currentuser = (WindowsIdentity)user.Identity;
var token = Currentuser.AccessToken
```